# (not nec. direct) sum of representations of linear algebraic group

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I'm very new to representation theory, so this is probably a very basic question.

Let $W_1, W_2$ be two subspaces of a $k$-vector space $V$. Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group and let $\rho: G \to \text{GL}(V)$ be a representation of $G$. Let $\rho_1: G \to \text{GL}(W_1)$, $\rho_2: G \to \text{GL}(W_2)$ be subrepresentations.

> Is there a way to find a subrepresentation $$\tilde{\rho}: G \to
>  \text{GL}(W_1+W_2)?$$

I think it would definitely be possible if $W_1+W_2$ was a direct sum, but I don't want to make this assumption.

I'm thinking that I could define it like this:

Let $w_1 + w_2 \in W_1 + W_2$ and let $g \in G$. We choose a basis $\{v_1, ..., v_n \}$ of $W_1 + W_2$ such that $\{v_1, ..., v_k \} \subset W_1$ and $\{v_{k+1}, ..., v_n \} \subset W_2$. We write

$$w_1 + w_2 = a_1 v_1+ ...+ a_n v_n, \ a_i \in k$$
and define

$$\tilde{\rho}(g)(w_1 + w_2) = \rho_1(g)(a_1 v_1)+ ... + \rho_1(g)(a_k v_k)+ \rho_2(g)(a_{k+1} v_{k+1})+ ... + \rho_2(g)(a_n v_n).$$

Could this work?

Comment: If $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are subrepresentations then their actions are just the restricted action of $\rho$. So they agree on the intersection. I.e. letting $g(w_1 + w_2) = gw_1 + gw_2$ is well defined. Should be the same as you defined.

Comment: Sounds good @JacobFG, thank you.